# Install php-bcmath on Debian 9

Tags: php, aptitude, debian-stretch

I am trying to install the `php-bcmath` extension on a Debian9 system, but all I get is

> unable to find package.

The command I use:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-bcmath
```

I tried it as well with `aptitude`, but it doesn't seem to work either.